# simple Http request hangs while executed in Visual Studio, works in powershell

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to execute an http request with C# with `HttpClient`. However each time when I call the GetAsync the code hangs. similar story in powershell.

that's my working java sample:

```
Authenticator.setDefault( new Authenticator()
{
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        return new PasswordAuthentication( "userName", "pwd".toCharArray());
    }
});
URL url = new URL( "http://serverName.com/ur?fields=cams_id;email");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod( "GET");
conn.setRequestProperty( "Accept", "application/json");

if( conn.getResponseCode() != 200) { throw new RuntimeException( "Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode()); }

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( (conn.getInputStream())));

String output;
System.out.println( "Output from Server .... \n");
while( (output = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println( output);
}

conn.disconnect();
```

I tried to write it like this in C#:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoTheTest()
    {
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("userName", "pwd") })
        {
            HttpClient cons = new HttpClient(handler);
            cons.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://serverName.com/");
            cons.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            cons.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            using (cons)
            {
//always hangs here.
                var response = await cons.GetAsync("ur?fields=cams_id;email");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return response;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

However, it doesn't work. Can you help me with the "translation"?

Btw, this code works for me in powershell. So far nothing works in C#:

```
$user = 'userName'
$pass = 'pwd'

$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"

$encodedCreds =   [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))

$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

$Headers = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}


Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://serverName.com/ur?fields=cams_id;email'-Headers $headers
```

and this one again doesn't work in Visual Studio C#:

```
        WebRequest httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://serverName.com/ur?fields=cams_id;email");
        ((HttpWebRequest)httpWebRequest).ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        String username = "userName";
        String password = "pwd";
        String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        //hangs here, too
        using (var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Assert.IsTrue(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result));
        }
```

Comment: you should avoid calling `.Result` of an asynchronous method. use `async / await` instead.

Comment: does this create the problem? results come in under a sec, I just first want to make it work at all.

Comment: this downvoting questions immediately without an obvious reason brings me almost to despair.

Comment: I suspect that it is defaults to http1.1.  Yo uneed to set client to http1.0 like this :             HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: 1 of the reasons for downvote could be you used a tag with a description of ``DO NOT USE - Use [apache-commons-httpclient], [apache-httpclient-4.x] or [dotnet-httpclient]``

Comment: Not a downvoter here but `However, it doesn't work.` doesn't mean anything. Any exceptions? Or it just hangs? Or whatever else?

Comment: @WiktorZychla - it just hangs.

Comment: @KirkLarkin: the supplied answer sounds like a correct one then.

Comment: There wasn't so much downvoting in the past, really, I used to write questions far more carelessly and they weren't downvoted, now I am kind of afraid to ask at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with the code but with the machine. After killing Sophos SSL VPN Client the code ran without problems. Still not sure why powershell worked and c# (in VS or outside) did not.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely your call to `.Result` is causing a deadlock. You should refactor the method to use async/await.

```
public async Task BasicTest()
```

Then, you'll want to update the `GetAsync` call to:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await cons.GetAsync("ur?fields=cams_id;email");
```

EDIT: It looks like the request is timing out. I believe the default timeout is 100 seconds.

Try changing the timeout to see if that's causing your hang:

```
cons.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```